# Reg: Python Open a file, read it, print matching lines

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need help to write script for reading log file and based on keyword match need to print and then I'd like to push that data in mongodb.

Please let me know with few examples and in detail, so that It will help me to start.

I look forward to hear from you.

Many Thanks,
Madhu.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The site's meant for programming problems, not for posting a list of requirements expecting others to do your work. It'd help if you tell us what you've tried, what specific bit you're stuck with, and what you've tried to do to solve those problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open with with `open()` method.
2. Read content Line by line.
3. if line text match with find text then print the line.

sample code:

To open file

```
>>> file_path = '/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/source.txt' 
>>> with open(file_path, "rb") as fp:
...    content = fp.read()
...
```

Code to read file line by line

```
>>> with open(file_path, "rb") as fp:
...    for i in fp.readlines():
...       print i
...
```

Use if to check find text present in the line or not

```
>>> if "abc" in "2015 user abc":
...    print "abc is present in line."
... 
abc is present in line.
```